# Javascript JSON.stringify text with \\n not showing Javascript string with new line

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to convert a string to JSON in javascript and send the string to a textarea HTML element.  The string from the backend looks as follows:

```
"customBar_query": "select\\n\\neq.Name,\\nAVG(Payload) as [Average Payload]\\n\\nfrom tbl.Cycles as c\\nleft join dim.Equipment as eq on eq.Id = c.Truck_Id\\nwhere c.Timestamp_Loading >= DATEADD(day,-365,GETDATE())\\n\\nGROUP BY eq.Name\\n\\nORDER BY [Average Payload] DESC"
```

The `"\\n"` string is supposed to be a valid newline representation.

I'm parsing the string as follows:

```
var newChartData = JSON.parse(data);
```

The resulting Javascript string looks as follows:

```
customBar_query: "select\n\neq.Name,\nAVG(Payload) as [Average Payload]\n\nfrom tbl.Cycles as c\nleft join dim.Equipment as eq on eq.Id = c.Truck_Id\nwhere c.Timestamp_Loading >= DATEADD(day,-365,GETDATE())\n\nGROUP BY eq.Name\n\nORDER BY [Average Payload] DESC"
```

So far so good.  Everything looks OK.  However, when browsing the object in Developer Tools, I don't see the normal "enter" symbol indicating a new line.  When assigning this value to a textarea using jquery .val(), the text is shown with the "\n" string and obviously without the real new lines as follows:

> select\n\neq.Name,\nAVG(Payload) as [Average Payload]\n\nfrom
>   tbl.Cycles as c\nleft join dim.Equipment as eq on eq.Id =
>   c.Truck_Id\nwhere c.Timestamp_Loading >=
>   DATEADD(day,-365,GETDATE())\n\nGROUP BY eq.Name\n\nORDER BY [Average
>   Payload] DESC

I just cannot figure out what's going on here.  It's not supposed to act in this manner and I really don't understand why it's doing this.  Any advice will be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

See below for a snippet from Chrome Developer Tools to show that the string \n is not show as an "enter" symbol

[image]

Comment: html doesn't support `\n` use `<br>` instead of it.

Comment: I tried on my browser and I'm quite seeing the `enter` symbols

Comment: @SRana they are talking about inserting this as value of a textarea here, so of course newlines are “supported” in that context.

Comment: "*The `"\\n"` string is supposed to be a valid newline representation.*" - no. The proper newline representation is `"\n"`.

Comment: @Bergi not for JSON.  JSON requires \\n.  \n does not parse

Comment: @ceds No, `\n` is a valid character sequence in a JSON string? Please show us what exactly you are getting from the backend and how.

Answer (score 0):

The values are strings. They are not yet newlines. Also we expect to see newlines represented as \n in a string and just a newline in the log

This shows the data with newlines in a textarea

```js
const jsonstring = `{"customBar_query": "select\\n\\neq.Name,\\nAVG(Payload) as [Average Payload]\\n\\nfrom tbl.Cycles as c\\nleft join dim.Equipment as eq on eq.Id = c.Truck_Id\\nwhere c.Timestamp_Loading >= DATEADD(day,-365,GETDATE())\\n\\nGROUP BY eq.Name\\n\\nORDER BY [Average Payload] DESC"}`
const obj = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
const txtArea = document.getElementById("x");
const pre = document.getElementById("output")
Object.values(obj).forEach(val => {
  txtArea.value += val;
  output.textContent += val;
})

console.log(pre.innerHTML)
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="x"></textarea>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: If the given example works then it is not a [mcve] which is reason for a VtC and not to add an answer o.O

Comment: @Andreas If that is the case, then the question can be closed as "not reproducible" but if OP did not do the last step, then it is an answer

Comment: Yeah as said it's supposed to work but it ain't giving me the same results in my code.  I posted an image showing how the browser interprets the string

Comment: @ceds they are strings. Please post the code where you expect to see them as text objects

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem.  It seems like '\n' is indeed proper syntax for JSON to be parsed in Javascript.  What happened was I had two different data sources pulling from the same function.  However, the difference was the first was injected via Django ({{dashboardJson|safe}}) into the HTML file and the second was through Javascript Ajax.

The Django '|safe' function messed around with the `\n` values and thus I had to send `\\n` in order for the JSON to be valid.  However, the Javascript Ajax only required `\n` and not `\\n` which caused it to render invalid strings.

I have no idea what Django changed as the strings looked fine to me, however something definitely happend there.